# How to fix datalist style/formating

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

How to fix datalist style/formating

I am using html, css, bootstrap, asp vb.net and datalist

I have a datalist, which had 3 cols and 2 rows.
Each col has a image, name, price.

Issue is that name can be in 1 line or in 2 lines or 3 lines for long names.
Becuase of this it is ruining the datalist format. any idea how can i fix this?

below is an example:

```
|-------|-------|-------|
| Image | Image | Image |
| Name  | Name  | Name  |
| Line1 | Line2 | 120   | 
|  120  | 120   }--------|
|-------|-------|   
                |-------| 
                | Image |
                | Name  |
                | Line3 |
                | 122   |
                |-------|
|-------|-------| 
| Image | Image | 
| Name  | Name  |
|  120  | 120   }
|-------|-------|
```

below if my datalist code with bootstrap

```
<asp:DataList ID="repeaterGrid" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" cssClass="row">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="text-center col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/" + Eval("Picture_Path").ToString().Trim() %>' style="width:245px;height:400px;"/>
                <h4 class="Text-Spacing"><%# Eval("Name")%></h4>
                <h5><strong>$<%# Eval("Price") %></strong></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4? (the code would be different depending on version)

Comment: i am using bootstrap 3